# Get highest value of Oracle table while using Max

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the follow sql statement.  I'm trying to get the highest version.  My query is returning multiple results, although sorted by verison desc.  How can I just get the highest one?

```
SELECT pv.version, pv.vin, pv.policyid, pv.segeffdate, pv.segexpdate, pv.changenum from
    nsa_al.polvehicle pv
WHERE pv.vin = '2GTEC19T011201788'
AND pv.changenum > 0
AND pv.VERSION = (SELECT MAX(PV.VERSION) FROM NSA_AL.POLVERSION)
ORDER BY pv.version DESC
```

I've tried to use the rownum = 1 but I kept getting missing ")" error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  Here is one with a subquery and `ROWNUM`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT pv.version, pv.vin, pv.policyid, pv.segeffdate, pv.segexpdate, pv.changenum 
    FROM nsa_al.polvehicle pv
    WHERE pv.vin = '2GTEC19T011201788'
        AND pv.changenum > 0
    ORDER BY pv.version DESC
) t
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dec0e/2)

This will only return a single record.  If you need ties, you can use the analytic function `RANK()` instead.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY version DESC) rnk, pv.version, pv.vin,  pv.changenum
    FROM pv
    WHERE pv.vin = '2GTEC19T011201788'
        AND pv.changenum > 0
    ORDER BY pv.version DESC
) t
WHERE rnk = 1
```

---

If you prefer to use a `MAX` aggregate, then it's easiest to do that with a common table expression and `JOIN` the table back on itself.  This could yield multiple results if there are multiple records with the same version:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT pv.version, pv.vin,  pv.changenum
    FROM pv
    WHERE pv.vin = '2GTEC19T011201788'
        AND pv.changenum > 0
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE C
  JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(version) maxVersion 
    FROM CTE) C2 ON C.version = C2.maxVersion
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dec0e/8)

Comment: thanks!  My vin I provided will actually be a variable in my program.  So I need this sql statement to pull the max version for many possible policies and/or vin numbers.  Will the first one work for this?  It worked for that particular vin.

Comment: @bucs10us -- if you need to group by vin, then I'd use the analytic functions instead of ROWNUM -- try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91d07/2 -- but if you are supplying the vin, then any of these options should work.  Kind regards.

Comment: My program is pulling multiple vins and policy ids.  I do not know which one will have a match inside another database.  I need to be sure that when I run my query, it will pick up the max version for all of the vins and policy ids.  I can have two vins and policy ids, but hundreds of versions for each vin or policy.  This is where I need to select only the highest, or max version.  I assume this will work.  Thanks @sgeddes